# Why does ffmpeg have bigger latency on dark images?

Tags: c#, image, video, ffmpeg

I have a c# application to stream real camera images using ffmpeg. The input images are in raw, 8-bit gray-scale format. I created an ffmpeg stream using the standard input to feed the images and send the output packages to websocket clients.

I start an external ffmpeg process using this config:

```
-f rawvideo -pixel_format gray -video_size " + camera.Width.ToString() + "x" + camera.Height.ToString() + " -framerate 25 -i - -f mpeg1video -b:v 512k -s 320x240 -
```

Typical image size is 1040*1392 pixels

I display the stream on the browser, using jsmpeg library

This works with a reasonable latency (~500ms on *localhost*), but when the camera image is really dark (black image), the latency is extremely big (~2-3 seconds on *localhost*). When there is something bright on the image again after a black period, it takes ~2-3 seconds to "synchronize".

I was thinking that black images are really easy to compress and will generate really small packages, jsmpeg has almost no information to display and wait until a complete data package arrives, but I couldn't prove my theory.

I played with ffmpeg parameters like *bitrate* and *fps* but nothing has changed.

Is there any settings which I could try?

Comment: Show full log. Does camera reduce framerate in low light?

Comment: The camera is an industrial camera and the images are acquired by software trigger. The framerate is constant, it is independent from the bright/light images.

Comment: Share full log of a run where the input images change from bright to dark.

Answer (score 1):

The size of image depends on how much noise creeps in.  Bright images usually have lesser noise and have clear areas which compress into smaller sizes.

Comment: This assumes that the "latency" is caused by either CPU or Network bottleneck?

Comment: This shows the relationship between size and image brightness.. To find out the actual problem, more data is needed as indicated by Mulvya..